# nginx reverse proxy "catch-all" location

Tags: nginx-location

EDIT: To be more clear, this is nginx version 1.13.8.

Take the following as an example nginx.conf file:

```
http {
    upstream portal_backend {
        server pc-loc43-01:15080;
    }
    upstream auth_backend {
        server pc-loc43-01:16080;
    }
    server {
        listen       9080 default_server;
        server_name  my-reverse-proxy;

        location / {
            auth_basic off;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

            proxy_pass http://portal_backend/;
        }
        location /auth {
            auth_basic off;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;

            proxy_pass http://auth_backend/auth;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to configure nginx to default to `location /` if it is unable to match the request to any of the locations, but I cannot find how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be related to how nginx does request matching -- somehow `auth` and `authorize` are too similar and it causes nginx problems (not a great explanation and maybe someone more experienced with nginx internals can chime in). The "solution" was to duplicate `location /` into `location /authorize`, so now the config file looks like:

```
...
    location / {
        auth_basic off;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;           
        proxy_pass http://portal_backend/;
    }
    location /authorize {
        auth_basic off;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;           
        proxy_pass http://portal_backend/;
    }
...
```

All the other routes work as I would have expected, e.g. `/users`, `/customers`, `/whatever` are all handled by `location /`

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything wrong with your code.

`location / {` is already the default location block for "unhandled" locations.

---

This would match all locations:

```
location / {
    # ...
}
```

This would match the root only:

```
location = / {
    # ...
}
```

This will match /auth and sub directories:

```
location /auth {
    # ...
}
```

Comment: After logging in the user is redirected to `<portal>/authorize#<token stuff>`, but nginx gives me a 404 for the `/authorize` route instead of letting `location /` handle the request

Comment: yes `/auth` is for the identity server (login/logout), `/authorize` is an endpoint on the portal for handling the redirect from the identity server after the user successfully logs in

Comment: although I think I just solved it by duplicating the `location /` into `location /authorize` and now it works, although I am confused because nginx has no problem routing `/users`, `/customers`, `/whatever` to the portal